# django rest-framework-2 No module named apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

guys can you help me a bit

I try to use Django REST Framework in my project but it doesn't work...

So i start with the QuickStart here: 
http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/tutorial/quickstart

But something wrong...

Comment: What have you tried? What's the structure of your project? Is django properly installed? Have you tried re-pulling django 1.6?

Comment: What is your version of the rest framework? The tutorial you are linking is for version 2.x, make sure you are not running DRF 3.x.

Comment: My bad i was using DRF 3.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx all, i fix it with :

```
pip uninstall djangorestframework
```

and

```
pip install 'djangorestframework<3.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you're following the rest framework version 2 tutorials, you have actually installed a version of DRF 3+.  I can tell this because of some code present in the traceback (in `compat.py`, the line showing `from django.apps import apps` is strictly DRF 3 code).

Rest framework [dropped support](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.3-announcement/) for Django v1.6 a while back.  Therefore, you'll need to choose one of the following options to proceed:

- Upgrade your Django version to 1.7+ and follow the [current quickstart guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/), or
- Downgrade your DRF version to version 2

Comment: He is using DRF version 2. It supports Django versions 1.4+.

Comment: Thanks, my bad -_-!

Comment: He is using a DRF2 tutorial and older version of Django. His problem seems to be that he inadvertently installed the wrong version of DRF. Your answer is still bad.

Comment: @MadWombat Why is the answer bad?  I pointed out the problem, and it helped the OP so that he could solve his problem.  How else could do you think I could edit it to improve it?